# Android Relative layout placement

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create an application that have list of icon like regular home on android.
The problem is, i can't manage it very well.
Here's the picture of the icon that i already done.

https://scontent-a-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/t1.0-9/10487441_10203329703355576_1539494398961024590_n.jpg

And here's the xml code that I create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconFoods"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"                
                android:src="@drawable/food"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iconFoods"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapecount"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:text="50"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />          

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iconFoods"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:text="Medium Text" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

My Question is, how can I make the image on the center of relative layout and how to set the space between image and textview. 
I already try to put padding top and layout margin top, but its still not working.

Comment: Can you post the image how do you want it to be? You want space between image and textview?

Comment: I want to create an icon like this https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-0/10403053_10203329753156821_7691990153695213434_a.jpg

Here's the icon that I already create so far.

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/q71/s720x720/10151895_10203329772837313_3200018448000502042_n.jpg

Comment: @user3561934 check my answer below. Hope you are expecting an output like that.

Comment: Use `GridView` and the layout I posted as `custom layout`. It will work good for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `android:layout_below` instead of `android:layout_alignBottom`.For this reason margin didn't work.
2. remove **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"** these attributes
3. make that `RelativeLayout's` width `match_parent` as u giving
   `weight` on it.

*P.S : Nested weights are bad*

try this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconFoods"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"                
            android:src="@drawable/food"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iconFoods"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shapecount"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="50"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />          

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iconFoods"
            android:text="Medium Text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. its work.
Btw, I know about the nested weight is bad. But I can't find another solution for it. If I didn't use nested weight its gonna look like this

https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t1.0-9/q71/s720x720/10464180_10203329866519655_1684631133287824958_n.jpg

But I don't want that there's a blank space in there. Is there any other solution for that?

Comment: how about using a `GridView`

Comment: Ok i'll try. Can I message u again if I have a little problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image below everything else by center-aligning it:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#CENTER_HORIZONTAL
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#CENTER_VERTICAL

Text view can be put below image by aligning the top of textView with the bottom of image
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#BELOW

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="center" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />


    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Meduim Text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the output

[image]

Make use of **GridView** and this as **Custom Layout**. It will work great for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some **changes with your view properties**...

in `textView1` instead of using

`android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iconFoods"` use

**`android:layout_below="@+id/iconFoods"`**

and then **use margin properties**... it will work then...

use below code...

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconFoods"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"                
    android:src="@drawable/food"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iconFoods"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shapecount"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:text="50"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />          

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iconFoods"
    android:text="Medium Text" />
```